# ADO.NET in Windows 8

Tags: ado.net, windows-8, windows-phone-8

Is there ADO.NET in Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8? I need SqlConnection class. Maybe there is additional libraries?

Comment: Every references of .NET Framework are included in project by default, but there is no SqlConnection class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer above is correct. Here is some follow up content, if needed.

Windows 8 applications are expected to run directly from the Windows Store, without the limitations imposed by connecting to local servers via a connection string.

The recommended approach is to expose your database via a web service.

Two Microsoft technologies that do this are:
(1) Windows Communication Foundation
(2) ASP.NET Web API (the more modern approach)

For Windows Communication Foundation, here is a tutorial:
http://www.intstrings.com/ramivemula/articles/create-a-simple-wcf-service-against-pubs-database-using-ef-linq-part-i/

For ASP.NET Web API, here is a tutorial:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASP-NET-Web-API-Tutorial-c4761894/view/SourceCode

Comment: I agree, the intent behind Windows 8 applications is exposing and manipulating information stored remotely. However, apps also need to be available in disconnected mode, which means some form of local storage is required.

Comment: WCF would be the recommended approach, as ASP.NET is for building web applications.  WCF provides Data Contracts to consumers like Win8 applications.  ASP.NET is not "the more modern approach."  They are for different purposes.

Answer (score 5):

There is no ADO.NET in WP8.  If you are referring to modern, Windows 8 Store Applications, ADO.NET is not allowed either.  ADO.NET would only be available in desktop applications.

Comment: Ok, thank you! But are there any ways to work with databases, except WCF services?

Comment: you can use SqlLite (an in memory database) with your Windows Store applications, but if you need to access a SQL Server variant, then it will need to be through some sort of service layer (like WCF).